# Disqus comments Dark mode renders with white background

Tags: disqus

I have written a custom webserver with a lot of effort put into making everything look good, however disqus loads with white text on dark mode when I force disqus to use dark mode(as currently I only support dark mode) the text switches to white with a white background which is unusable.

[image: a screenshot of the disqus comment setup with a white background and white text which makes it unreadable]

Is there something I am doing wrong? This is the only pain point holding me back from switching my old hugo blog to my new custom blog.

in case anyone wants to see my old blog is at https://nullrequest.com
and my new webserver is at https://new.nullrequest.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<meta name="color-scheme" content="dark" />` from your document.